# Add number from x to y to every row

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have a file which contains 1 word per line. I need to add every number from 75 to 99 to every row (aka word).
Example input file:

```
foo
bar
```

Example output to a new file

```
foo75
foo76
foo77
...
foo99
bar75
bar76
bar77
...
bar99
```

Comment: With some implementations of `join` (but not GNU `join`): `join -t '' -1 2 -2 2 file <( printf '%d\n' {75..99} )`

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
awk '{for (i=75;i<100;i++) print $0 i}' input_file > new_file
```

Comment: Numbers are entered on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

awk-less alternative:

```
while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "${line}"{75..99} ; done < input_file > output_file
```

Mind the placing of the quotes...